# Grandpa authorities in the context of pallet-staking

Tags: grandpa, genesis, pallet-staking

In `pallet-staking`'s genesis config there are two items :

```rust
pub validator_count: u32,
pub minimum_validator_count: u32,
```

Question : How are we to interpret them in the context of Grandpa finality? I know that to achieve finality a minimum of 2/3 of validators must vote on a chain to finalize it. So if I have `X` validators on Genesis and `Y` more validators join my set, would I be correct to assume that (2/3 of `X+Y`) are the current Grandpa authorities?